# where can i find the. details of a Kafka exception 'OffsetMetadataTooLargeException'?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to understand what could cause 'OffsetMetadataTooLargeException' from a kafka producer point of view but couldn't find any documentation. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> The client has tried to save its offset with associated metadata
> larger than the maximum size allowed by the server.

It is a [broker level configuration](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#offset.metadata.max.bytes)

> **offset.metadata.max.bytes**
>
> The maximum size for a metadata entry associated with an offset commit

The metadata of an offset is typically could be:

```
long: offset
Optional<Integer>: leaderEpoch
String: metadata
```

The `OffsetAndMetadata` is constructed for committing through `KafkaConsumer` ([Reference doc](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/OffsetAndMetadata.html)).

The `String: metadata` here is for..

> The Kafka offset commit API allows users to provide additional
> metadata (in the form of a string) when an offset is committed. This
> can be useful (for example) to store information about which node made
> the commit, what time the commit was made, etc.

Since you haven't pasted any code, I *assume* you may be using one of the following:

```
KafkaProducer#sendOffsetsToTransaction()
KafkaConsumer#commitAsync()
KafkaConsumer#commitSync()
```

where you might be giving a `Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata>` and that you are creating `OffsetAndMetadata` object with `String: metadata` parameter making it too large than the configured so that your offset and metadata becomes > 4096 bytes (default) or any value that you've explicitly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the details. This happens "The client has tried to save its offset with associated metadata larger than the maximum size allowed by the server."

http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/errors/OffsetMetadataTooLarge.html